# Hide/show divs when printing to printer

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

Is it possible to click on a button/image/link on a page and include/exclude other elements from being printed? (on an actual printer)
I'd like to give the users the selection of which elements to print. Is this feasible with jQuery of Javascript?

Edited for better understanding: I'd like to let the user choose which parts of the page he wants to print by adding a print this/don't print this button next to each div, overriding the default settings i've set in my print.css file.

Update: After Richard Neil Ilagan's suggestion, i've tried the following and I feel I'm close but cant nail it. Any suggestions?

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print { 
    .no-print { display:none; } 
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dontPrint').click(function() { $('maybe').addClass('no-print'); });
});
</script>

<img class="dontPrint" src="images/cancel.png" title="Dont print bla bla" /></a>
<div id="maybe">bla bla</div>
```

Comment: I already use a separate css stylesheet for printing, but can  this be done on the fly? I mean to select the printable elements just before printing?

Comment: @Somebodyintrouble: the code is needless my friend, it noting but a typical page with various divs etc...

Comment: You can probably set a class for a `print` media query to not print, like `@media print { .no-print { display:none; } }`, then assign the class to the stuff you don't want to shoot out the printer end using jQuery, like `$('div').addClass('no-print');`.

Comment: Nice idea, I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Haha, sure man. :) I do hope you're not using *actual* paper for testing though. :p

Comment: Please note that by adding those classes with jQuery, you break browser's native print functionality. I'm not saying don't do it, I'm saying know what you are doing :)

Comment: :) No, I'm using Firebug and test-printing to PDF, same thing I suppose.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. You can do that by using CSS's `@media print` media type selector. Example (hide all inputs when printing):

```
@media print {
    input {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

As a design pattern, you may combine print media selector with the rest stylesheets to achieve toggle effect.

HTML:

```
<div class="for-screen">
    <input type="submit" value="Shown when not printing">
</div>
<div class="for-print">
    <p>Shown instead when printing</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.for-screen {display: block;}
.for-print {display: none;}

@media print {
    .for-screen {display: none;}
    .for-print {display: block;}
}
```

More stuff on the matter:

- [Media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) on CSS2 standard
- [CSS Design: Going to print](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) (alistapart.com)

Comment: Thank you, i'm familiar with the @media print etc. But my question is slightly different... can you change the elements to be printed with a toggle control of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

you should set that with css.

**media="print"**

Try something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```