# No Print on background image of a div

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a DIV with a background image. I want the image to display on the screen (which works already) but I do NOT want that image to print when the page is printed. Is there a way in CSS to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe this question helps you:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086260/hide-show-divs-when-printing-to-printer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086260/hide-show-divs-when-printing-to-printer

Answer (score 2):

You can add a print stylesheet that removes the image for printing purposes...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Inside the print stylesheet, you just use normal CSS, which will only apply when printing, for example...

```
.myStyle {
    background-image:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a media query

```
@media print {
   #yourDiv { background-image:none; }
}
```

OR load a print specific style sheet where you overwrite the background.

Answer (score 1):

I think media queries will helpful for you

```
@media print
  {
     div.test {background:none;}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to target IE 8 or earlier, favour the print stylesheet approach, as these browsers don't support media queries.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  When answering a question, it is always a good idea to provide a code snippet/sample and any relevant links you can dig up that help make your answer more robust.